# PHPWORD - Insert image in front of text on every page of a docx file

Tags: php, docx, phpword

Using PhpWord library, please tell me if it is possible to insert an image in front of text and on every page, in the same position, when creating a new docx file.

Comment: If you want to insert an image to top of the page on every page, this you can easily achieve with global header - I doubt that there is any way (at least none that I could think of) if you want to insert an image really in front of the text (inline with text).

Comment: In order to be more clear: I have a document, with a single section, containing a table which can ocupy a page or more pages and I want to put a stamp/image on every page, in the same place, in front of the text from table. ejuhjav, thank you for your idea. I tried it, building the final docx from two steps: one step builds a document with a fake header and the second one loads the document and attach the correct stamp in the header, but without good results for me. This was scenario proposed by you? Can be more specific and perhaps give a slice of code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a development version which implements this:

Have a look at this issue: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/939

This pull request implements this: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/pull/1084

Comment: Your idea is based on template, but my docx file is created from scratch and  does not use template. Is this possible to solve m issue in these conditions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example to illustrate what I meant with using global header to place an image in the top of every page (with single section containing a long table):

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection();

$header = $section->addHeader();
$header->addImage('resources/PhpWord.png', array('width' => 80, 'height' => 80, 'alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc::START));

// generate long table just for demo that spans over multiple pages
$table = $section->addTable();
for ($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++) {
    $table->addRow();
    $table->addCell(4500)->addText('dummy');
    $table->addCell(4500)->addText("contents $i");
}
```

Comment: I have tried with text in header and, indeed, the text is changed. But, when I used image in header and, then, I tried to replace the image, the image is replaced, but not in front of the text anymore.